# modal, enviar datos, javascript, php, ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal

Buen día, en la imagen muestro un fragmento de código que es como llamo a todos mis **<figure** , el resto de código es el típico.
El otro fragmento de **script** es como cambio el valor que quiero mostrar en mi modal (solo de prueba).
Sin embargo, cuando selecciono `<a href="#dialog"...>` de diversos **<figure** , el valor que muestro de prueba es siempre el mismo y coincide con el del primer  **<figure**. ¿Por qué sucede?¿Se les hace conocido este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function realizaP(valorCaja1){
  var parametros ={
    "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1
  };
  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: './inda.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function (){
      $("#resul").html("Procesando");

    },
    success: function (response){
      $("#resul").html(response);
     
    }
    
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `while` simpre estas actualizando el input con `id="valor1"` o estas agregando un input con el mismo `id` por lo que al acceder `$("#valor1").val()` siempre a el mismo.

puedes solucionarlo agregando tu id directamente a la funcion o asignarle `id` diferente a tus inputs

Ejemplo:

```
onclick="realizaP(<?=$r['id']?>);return false;"
```

ó

```
<input type="hidden" name="caja_texto" id="valor<?=$r['id']?>" value="valor<?=$r['id']?>"/>
```

sugiero separa el código de vistas del codigo del lado servidor

Comment: muchas gracias jcHernande2